# Flask Routes all return 404

Tags: python, flask

I have been trying to move from using sqlite to sqlalchemy for a project. This has caused me to move many files and I appear to ruined my app routing and I can not explain how. See below for code and file structure. In short the only route I can now get back and working is the Swagger UI I have built and that probably only works because flask does not handle its route to my knowledge. Any help would be much appreciated. Keep in mind I am new to flask so if this is a very stupid issue forgive me, other answers on stackoverflow had eventually led to me creating the create_app function and while that does get the flask site running I imagine the @app.route's are not being called at all.
My file structure is like so:

```
Project
   |--- project.py (Runs the project)
   |--- Config.py (Holds the class config)
   |--- web 
   |  |--- __init__.py (See below)
   |  |--- routes.py (Hols the routes)
   |  |--- api (Swagger ui and other scripts)
   |  |  |--- __init__.py
   |  |  |--- swagger.yaml
```

My project.py:

```
from web import create_app
import db
import os

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
else:
    if not os.path.exists("./Project.db"):
        print(" * Building Database")
        db.build_db()
        print(" * Database built")
    print(" * Database exists")
```

My web/**init**.py:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from config import Config
import connexion

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = connexion.FlaskApp(__name__, specification_dir="./api")
    app.add_api("swagger.yaml")
    app = app.app
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    db.init_app(app)
    return app
#migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from web import routes, models
```

My web/routes.py: (Snipped for brevity)

```
#! python3
from web import create_app, routes
from web.forms import LoginForm
import web.api
import flask

app = create_app()

#############
# Home URLs #
#############
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('home'))
    return flask.render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)

@app.route("/web")
def home():
    devices = web.api.devices.get()
    for device in devices:
        device.update({"model": web.api.models.get_devices_model(device["alias"])["model"]})
    return flask.render_template("home.html", devices=devices)
```

Comment: What's the basePath in swagger.yaml? Not an expert on connexion, but it looks like you're bypassing your own routes, and instead only using the Swagger config. I would expect `specification_dir="./"`, then `app.add_api("./api/swagger.yaml")`

Comment: The base path is just /, it is like this due to trying to keep compatibility with a different programs api. Though this did work before, I decided to try changing the base path to /api for swagger, and I am left with the same issue. I can get to the swagger ui at /api/ui but my web base paths like /web and /login are both met with 404's

Comment: Is that what happens when you try my suggestion?

Comment: When I try your suggestion I have the same problem as before, the only thing that changes is the api ui is moved to a different route. So instead of /ui I can move it to /api/ui but the error with my routes all returning 404's is still there.